# Enable Features with Apex

Tags: apex, automation, notes

Is it possible to automate (preferably with apex) enabling of features from setup.

For example if I want enable the notes settings in a org I would have nav to Setup > Build > Customize > Notes > Notes Settings and click 'Enable Notes' then the save button.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I see that it would be less effort to do this in Apex than by using the UI.

Comment: The idea is to be able to click a button then install + configure the enviroment with the product.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a [Metadata API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) and a [Tooling API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_tooling.pdf) that can both be called from Apex - see e.g. [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). I am not sure if the setting you mention is included especially as the page itself mentions some additional steps - you would have to carefully check the documentation.

But another aspect of this is should you make such a choice in code? Remember that your application is typically not the only one in your Salesforce instance and your set of users are not the only users. So I suggest you think very carefully about what (if any) settings of this sort to automatically configure.

Configuration that only impacts your app can be safely automatically configured.